# Using Twillo to send SMS with Alexa

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to use Twillo programmable SMS to send a message through Alexa. The sample code provided by Twillo works when I just run it in a command line but when I incorporate the same code into the index.js file of an Alexa skill it is not invoking. Can someone please look at the code and suggest what changes I should make.

```
var accountSid = '[account-sid]';
var authToken = '[auth-token]';
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
...

var handlers = {
'HouseKeepingIntent': function() {
var Itemslot = this.event.request.intent.slots.Item;
var Itemname = Itemslot.value;
this.attributes['speechOutput'] = this.t("HOUSEKEEPING_MESSAGE", Itemname);
this.attributes['repromptSpeech'] = this.t("HOUSEKEEPING_REPROMPT", Itemname);
this.emit(':ask', this.attributes['speechOutput'],        this.attributes['repromptSpeech']);

client.messages.create({
to: "+[number-to]",
from: "+[number-from]",
body: "Housekeeping is needed?",
}, function(err, message) {
if (err) console.log(err.message);
if (message) console.log(message.sid);});
};
```

In other examples I have seen the Twillo API is being called through http but the format in above seems to be different.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this your actual code?  If so, you're missing a closing curly brace to terminate your function.  Also, are you able to create a Twilio client elsewhere by simply supplying account SID and auth token to the module?  The [sdk docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node#testing-your-installation) use `new twilio.RestClient(accountSid, authToken)`.  Finally, it would be very helpful if you could describe the result better than 'not invoking'.  Is it throwing an error?  Have you tried to add logging to determine where it fails?

Comment: Fissure thanks for your comments. I extracted the HouseKeepingIntent function from my very long code to provide some context. It works when installed. The problem I am having is in generating the SMS message. When I use the code (client.messages.create etc) in a stand alone js file an SMS successfully generates. My problem is why won't the same SMS generate when I invoke it within the HouseKeeping function?

Comment: How are you running this, is it via AWS Lambda? If so have you got the Twilio dependency uploaded too?  Also, are there any errors shown in the logs?

Comment: @Jay yes I am running this on AWS Lambda and have the Twilo dependency uploaded. The logs show that the code for the API isn't being accessed because once it invokes this.emit(':ask', this.attributes['speechOutput'],        this.attributes['repromptSpeech']); it shuts down.

Comment: Hi Farhan Memon, have you figured out a solution? I have the same problem with AWS and twilio. Could you help me please?

Comment: This is from 2017, why is it now appearing as the most recent item in the Alexa question list ?